# Partitioning a vector into all possible combinations of paired values

Tags: r, combinations

I have a vector with different values (the length of the vector is an even number). Let's say k = c(1,2,3,4).

I want to partition k into pairs, and enumerate all the possible unique combinations of pairs, without replacement.
Each result should be a list containing k/2 different unique pairs. Also, the elements of the list (ie the pairs) should be different in the sense of identity and order.

So in the example above, the results should be as follows. (Ideally all the results will be in a list of lists, each containing one unique partitioning)

result 1: 
pair1 = 1,2; pair2 = (3,4)

result 2: 
pair1 = 1,3; pair2 = (2,4)

result 3: 
pair1 = 1,4; pair2 = (2,3)

So the result (2,1); (3,4) and (3,4); (1,2) are not valid since there are identical to result 1 above.

Note that I don't only need to find all combinations of pairs, as combn (from
combinat package) provides. I need to divide the vector k by all pairs.

Also for this reason, the question is not a duplicate of any question dealing
with finding pairs only (without arranging/dividing the vector).

For my needs, k will be 14, so there are a lot of possibilities.

Do you have any idea how I can approach the problem.
I am working with R.

Thanks

Comment: The question is not a duplicate of the suggested question. The issue there was about finding all possible pairs and not dividing the vector.

Comment: You can get most of the way using this function: `pairer2 <- function(kn, pair_list) {
  
  pair1_partners <- lapply(kn, function(x) {
    
    partners <- Filter(function(t) !any(t %in% x), pair_list)
    
    if(length(partners) > 1) {
      
      pairer2(kn = partners[1:(length(partners)/2)], partners)
    } else {return(partners)}
  })
  
  return(mapply(function(x,y) {list(root = x, partners = y)}, kn, pair1_partners, SIMPLIFY = F))
}
`

Comment: and then `pair_combn <- function(k, n = 2) {
  
  p <- combn(k, n, simplify = F)
  
  pairer2(kn = p[1:(length(k)-1)], p)}
`. If you run `pair_combn(14)` it will give you all the unique pairs from a length 14 vector. It does take a while, and also takes up significant memory. The output is as a nested list, which is not very convenient. I haven't worked out how to successfully collapse this yet.